# PhantomJS is not allowed to load local resource

Tags: jquery, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

When trying to to load a local json file using `$.getJSON` in PhantomJS, I get the error message:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file://test.json.

```
describe('AJAX', function () {
    it('$.getJSON', function (done) {
        $.getJSON('file://test.json', function (data) {
            assert.strictEqual(data.string_property, 'string');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I have already tried using the command line arguments `--web-security=false` and `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` but I consistently get the same error message.

Comment: Do the PHP script's run ok by them selves. have you done a test to make sure its not a web server issue? also have you monitored the apache error log file to see if any security issues

Comment: I do not use PHP at all and there is no Apache Server involved!

Comment: i dont know how i thought it was PHP :(). I think i know the problem. Its the Control-Allow-Origin: * thats blocking you. Try this extension for google chrome and give it a Test -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file from the file system, you should use the [`fs`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) module. For example like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.read("test.json");
// do something with data
```

There is no command line option that you can use to allow PhantomJS to access local files from a remote location. `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` does something else. If you are on the about:blank page, then you are allowed to access remote resources.

I've looked through the command line flags of Chrome and haven't found one that would allow such a thing.